# Issue with using animationcurve for button click animation [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a button that animates on click and uses an animationcurve for the click animation.  Works great.

Problem is, I'm screwing up somewhere in the coroutine and it causes the object the script is applied to, to snap back to world 0 when I click on it.  How do I move the object based on the curve wherever the object happens to be in world space, and not pop to world 0 on first click?

Here's my button script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour {

    //create a placeholder for the animation coroutine
    IEnumerator currentCoroutine;

    //create public animation curve for adjustments
    public AnimationCurve curveAnim;

    public float posDisplacement;  //animation value (movement distance, opacity, etc.)
    public float speed;  //the speed at which the animation curve should complete in (like a magnitude)

    //animaiton coroutine
    IEnumerator kickback(){
        float curveTime = 0f;  //beginning time of the animation curve
        float curveAmount = curveAnim.Evaluate (curveTime);  //a place to store the value of the curve at any point in time

        //while loop to execute the curve until it completes
        while (curveTime < 1.0f) {
            curveTime += Time.deltaTime * speed;  //reference curve at time - speed affects the duration at which the curve completes
            curveAmount = curveAnim.Evaluate (curveTime);  //store the current curve value from the time * speed

            //do something using the value of the curve at time

            //this will move the current object in z in reference to the animaiton curve by multiplying the value of the curve by the animation value
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, curveAmount*posDisplacement); ]

            //break after completing
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //Button events

    void OnTouchDown(){
        //Debug.Log ("Touch Down!");
    }

    void OnTouchUp(){

        //check if a coroutine is already running.  If so, stop it and then start it again
        if (currentCoroutine != null) {
            StopCoroutine (currentCoroutine);
        }

        currentCoroutine = kickback();  //assign what the currently running coroutine is
        StartCoroutine (currentCoroutine);  //run the current coroutine OnTouchUp
        //Debug.Log ("Touch Up!");
    }

    void OnTouchStay(){
        //Debug.Log ("Staying...");
    }

    void OnTouchExit(){
        //Debug.Log ("Exited");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using transform.localposition instead of transform.position?

Comment: Yup, same result.  I think it has something to do with the way i'm trying to update only the z axis of the game object, but I don't know of other options I may have for trying to update the object's position.  I'm multiplying a float by an animationcurve, so I'm assuming if my curve ends at 0, position would be 0.  If that's the case, maybe I'm trying to move my object in the wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Just figured out a solution.  Based on the suggestion from ZayedUpal to try using `transform.localPosition`, I realized that this alone wouldn't be enough because its only referencing its self.  However, if I parent this object to an empty game object and then run, and use the parent to reposition the button, it works as intended!

So to reiterate, updating the `tranform.position` to `transform.localPosition` and then parenting the object to an empty game objet got the result I was expecting.

If anyone has a better solution, please post it, but for now, this works just fine for me.